# Can I put my business signature on my personal email?

Tags: email

In other words, include my title and the name of my employer in my personal email signature in my personal email.

Comment: I don't think this is a legal question, it's more a matter of workplace policy.

Comment: @RonBeyer unfortunately it's a matter of a specific company's policy, which is actually one of our close reasons on Workplace. This question will likely be closed quickly.

Comment: @Michael - you should ask your employer if they have a policy for this. Many employers will likely tell you not to do this.

Comment: @dwizum I didn't mean it should be migrated, I'm sure it is off-topic as well here.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea to me, it could potentially cause issues for you or your employer.  For example, a personal opinion that you write in a personal email could be interpreted as your employer's official position on the issue.

Comment: I think that this question is highly answerable. It can be company-specific, but it can be answered in a general way (as in "is it a good idea/professional/etc to do so")

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can, but I wouldn't advise it, for the following reason.

**Every last email  you send with that information reflects on the company**

In other words, if you compose an email that offends someone, and it gets back to your employer, you are out of luck.

It is far too much of a risk to use in anything other than professional correspondence.

Answer (score 7):

It's a bad idea.

It would cause confusion. There are two identities: your personal one, and your work one. These should be kept separate.

If you start sending emails like this and somebody notices that the signature doesn't match the email domain, it will damage both your reputation and your company.

I would myself take this as impersonating somebody else and potential scam attempt.

Comment: I generally agree with this answer and I even upvoted it. That being said, there is one exception to this and that's alumni association emails. On an alumni mailing list, people tend to indicate who they work for, but at the same time, they don't want the extra noise of those emails to be comingled with work emails inside their company inbox.